# not able to open any web page in IE by using Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to open a google page (google.com) in IE but on running my script it is showing " org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) is showing on running " error.
I am using IE:- 11
windows :- 8.1; 64bit.

My Code Is:-

```
System.setProperty("Webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.co.in");
//  driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); 
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());    
    String PageTitle = driver.getTitle();
Thread.sleep(3000);

    if (PageTitle.equals("Google")){
        System.out.println("test case passed");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("failed");
    }
```

Comment: which version selenium jars you are using ?

Comment: @Rohit I am working on Selenium 2.51

Comment: ok I will check with 2.51

Comment: with 2.51 also, it is working fine at my end

Comment: are you using IE11?

Comment: are you using IE11:-  yes

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code : this is working fine at my end

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities cappabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();        
    cappabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
    cappabilities.setCapability("platform", "WIN8"); 
    cappabilities.setCapability("version", "11"); 
    cappabilities.setCapability("browserName", "internet explorer");
    cappabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",1);
    cappabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents","false");
    cappabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus","true");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cappabilities);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://google.co.in");
       System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); 
         Thread.sleep(3000);
         System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());    
        String PageTitle = driver.getTitle();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

        if (PageTitle.equals("Google")){
            System.out.println("test case passed");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("failed");
        }
```

And Please let me know if this is working at your end

Screenshot :- [image]

[image]

Comment: I have used selenium 3.4.0 jars

Comment: And one more thing .... write "webdriver.ie.driver" instead of "Webdriver.ie.driver"

Comment: the code that i have posted is working fine at my end...with IE11 windows 8.1, 64 bit, selenium 2.51...I will try something new to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

First Set the Protected Mode settings in IE Browser. kindly follow the below steps:

1. Open IE Browser
2. Click on setting
3. Click on Internet Option
4. Go to Security tab
5. Click on the Internet zone to Select a zone and to view its Protected Mode property.
6. Now check the Enable Protected Mode check-box.
7. Needs to be set for all the other zones. (Internet, Local Intranet, Trusted Sites, Restricted Sites)
8. Click OK
9. Again click on setting
10. Make sure that the Internet Explorer’s Zoom property is set to 100%

Use the below capability in your Selenium script:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false); capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURIY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
capabilities.setCapability("allow-blocked-content", true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

run the Selenium script again. It will work this time.